# shiro annotation is not working in grails. Can anybody suggest me what is wrong?

Tags: grails, shiro

When I used `@RequiresPermissions` I got cannot resolve symbol 'RequiresPermissions' error. I already have imported `org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresPermissions`.
Annotations are used as `@RequiresPermissions("module:books:list")`

My authorization class

```
class AuthController {

    def shiroSecurityManager

    def index = { redirect(action: "login", params: params) }

    def login = {
        return [ username: params.username, rememberMe: (params.rememberMe != null), targetUri: params.targetUri ]
    }

    def signIn = {
        def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(params.username, params.password as String)

        // Support for "remember me"
        if (params.rememberMe) {
            authToken.rememberMe = true
        }

        // If a controller redirected to this page, redirect back
        // to it. Otherwise redirect to the root URI.
        def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/"

        // Handle requests saved by Shiro filters.
        SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getSavedRequest(request)
        if (savedRequest) {
            targetUri = savedRequest.requestURI - request.contextPath
            if (savedRequest.queryString) targetUri = targetUri + '?' + savedRequest.queryString
        }

        try{
            // Perform the actual login. An AuthenticationException
            // will be thrown if the username is unrecognised or the
            // password is incorrect.
            SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)

            log.info "Redirecting to '${targetUri}'."
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex){
            // Authentication failed, so display the appropriate message
            // on the login page.
            log.info "Authentication failure for user '${params.username}'."
            flash.message = message(code: "login.failed")

            // Keep the username and "remember me" setting so that the
            // user doesn't have to enter them again.
            def m = [ username: params.username ]
            if (params.rememberMe) {
                m["rememberMe"] = true
            }

            // Remember the target URI too.
            if (params.targetUri) {
                m["targetUri"] = params.targetUri
            }

            // Now redirect back to the login page.
            redirect(action: "login", params: m)
        }
    }

    def signOut = {
        // Log the user out of the application.
        SecurityUtils.subject?.logout()
        webRequest.getCurrentRequest().session = null

        // For now, redirect back to the home page.
        redirect(uri: "/")
    }

    def unauthorized = {
        render "You do not have permission to access this page."
    }
}
```

My application runs but when I login by using user that I have set, it directly sends me to unauthorized page. I have allowed some permissions to the user.

Comment: Please post the code and the entire error message

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the Javadoc](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/annotation/RequiresPermissions.html) for that annotation (or the source) you'll see that it's allowed to be assigned to types (class-level) and methods (`@Target(value={TYPE,METHOD})`). You are defining your controller actions as closures, which is still supported in Grails 2.0+ but methods are preferred now. You cannot use that annotation on closures, since they are not methods even though Grails and Groovy let you use them like methods. If the `Target` annotation included `FIELD` in addition to the other types it would work, but it doesn't because the Shiro library doesn't have direct support for closures in Grails controllers.

So change all of your actions from closures to methods, e.g.

```
def index() { redirect(action: "login", params: params) }

def login() {
   ...
}

....
```

and then you can annotate them.

Comment: this problem is solved.Now when I try to access the page not granted to the user it throws an exception.can't we redirect to the home page if user tries to access ungranted page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Shiro. Ask a new question with the exception message and stacktrace, and feel free to accept this answer :)